# Jetpack compose performance

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am learning Jetpack compose, I have noticed that the applications performance is lower than the android old way applications [XML and views]. Also you can see this clearly in scrollable lists, However, I have used components like lazy column which should be comparable to Recycler view, but the performance difference appears specially when scrolling, so you can see stuttering and glitches in the app. Therefore, is there any solution to this, or this happens because the Compose is new and needs time to be enhanced and get better.

Comment: That is partly a question of tooling (enable R8 on `debug` builds, wait for JIT to take effect) and partly a question of your code (as you can have poor performance in a `RecyclerView` as well). See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ry-3xlElUe4) for some advice, and see [this material](https://jetc.dev/issues/090#and-one-more-thing) for one specific source of difficulty (overcomposing, where you cause excessive recompositions). You might also consider asking a separate SO question with a [mcve] for help with your specific code.

Comment: The code I am working with is from the Google materials and code labs, and follows their best practices, Here is it [https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-theming#0], however, I will consider asking another question with detailed example. thanks.

Comment: Ah, also, [here is a blog post](https://engineering.premise.com/measuring-render-performance-with-jetpack-compose-c0bf5814933) from the developer who recorded that presentation video.